# Getting error while running Ecto Seed file

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir

I am new in Phoenix Framework and Elixir. I am trying to run seeder function for multiple time . though it is populating data quite well or as expected but it does throw a error while execute.

Here is the seed file

```
alias FatLobster.Repo
alias FatLobster.Recipe
alias FatLobster.Place
alias FatLobster.Review
import Faker
defmodule RecurssionSeed do

  def multiply_seeder(x,n)
    when x <=n do
        recipe_seed
        place_seed
        review_seed
        x = x+1
        multiply_seeder(x,n)
    end


  def recipe_seed  do
    Repo.insert(%Recipe{
         recipe_title: Faker.Lorem.word ,
         recipe_description: Faker.Lorem.paragraph ,

         cover_img:  Faker.Avatar.image_url() ,
         picture_one: Faker.Avatar.image_url() ,
         picture_two: Faker.Avatar.image_url() ,
         picture_three: Faker.Avatar.image_url() ,
         user_id: Enum.random(1..1000),
         upvote_count: Enum.random(1..1000),
         downvote_count: Enum.random(1..1000)

        })
  end

    def place_seed do
      Repo.insert(%Place{
        places_title: Faker.Lorem.word,
        places_description: Faker.Lorem.paragraph,
        cover_img: Faker.Avatar.image_url(),
        picture_one: Faker.Avatar.image_url(),
        picture_two: Faker.Avatar.image_url(),
        picture_three: Faker.Avatar.image_url(),
        upvote_count: Enum.random(1..300),
        downvote_count: Enum.random(1..1000)



        })
    end

    def review_seed do
      Repo.insert(%Review{
        review_title: Faker.Lorem.word,
        review_description: Faker.Lorem.sentence,
        cover_img: Faker.Avatar.image_url,
        picture_one: Faker.Avatar.image_url,
        picture_two: Faker.Avatar.image_url,
        picture_three: Faker.Avatar.image_url,

        user_id: Enum.random(1..100),
        upvote_count: Enum.random(1..1000),
        downvote_count: Enum.random(1..250),



        })
    end
end


RecurssionSeed.multiply_seeder(1,25)
```

But while I run the seed command in terminal it shows error after populating the postgre database.

here is the error message,

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in RecurssionSeed.multiply_seeder/2
    priv/repo/seeds.exs:22: RecurssionSeed.multiply_seeder(26, 25)
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:68: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

Can someone please explain to me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a termination clause:

```
 def multiply_seeder(x,n) when x <= n do
 ...
 end
 def multiply_seeder(x,n), do: nil
```

Your function will currently never terminate. Since `n` is 25, when `x` reaches 26 you get the `FunctionClauseError`.

**Edit**

Functions are composed of their name (`multiply_seeder`) their arity (`2`) and their guard clauses. If you call a function and it does not have a match, you will get a `FunctionClauseError`.

When recursively calling functions, a good technique is to write your termination clauses first. So in this case, when `x` > `n` you want to stop recursing. So you could write:

```
def multiply_seeder(x, n) when x > n, do: nil
```

In this case, when `x` > `n` the recursion will stop. You can now put the body of your function in the catch all (also known as the Pokémon clause):

```
def multiply_seeder(x, n) when x > n, do: nil
def multiply_seeder(x,n) when x <=n do
    recipe_seed
    place_seed
    review_seed
    x = x+1
    multiply_seeder(x,n)
end
```

Note that order is important - the matches are evaluated top to bottom.

In this case, you do not need to implement a recursive function manually.

You can do something like:

```
Enum.each(1..25, fn _ ->
  recipe_seed
  place_seed
  review_seed
end)
```

Comment: yes ...it does ... go for 26 .. and do not terminate. But I did not get your answer .. any doc reference ?? and I am still getting error .. I am doing it wrong for sure. Can you Provide any references ...

Comment: Try the elixir getting started guide http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html

Comment: @code.prio Please see my update, hopefully it will explain your issue a little more clearly.

Comment: damn ... You are a Boss.... yes ... its all clear for me now ... I can sleep happily tonight. you rock @Gazler